# Does hashing and encrypting the same field weakens it?

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash

I have a field (regular field, not a password) that is being stored in the database twice: as a hash (SHA512) and as an encrypted value. Changing this setup would require many changes which I don't want to get myself into. My question: in the case that the database is broken into, does the fact that the field is being stored twice as a hash and encrypted weakens its security? why?

> Some people have said yes
>   because now they have 2 ways to
>   possibly crack it. Duh, I know that.
>   What I'm asking about is whether one
>   can be used to make cracking the other
>   easier? Can the very fact that the
>   field has 2 variations somehow make it
>   easier for the attacker to use one to
>   make cracking the other easier? Look at it this way: if the
>   attacker is given only variant A, it
>   would take them a day. If given only
>   variant B, it would take them 3 days.
>   If the attacker runs both cracks
>   independently, they would crack variant A
>   faster (it takes only a day). But if the attacker is given
>   both, they can crack one in just 6
>   hours. This is what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the hash and encryption method are cryptographically strong, then the attack would be brute force. So the cost would be to run the weaker of the two: hash or encryption. If the hash is computed with a large number of iterations (e.g., with PBKDF2) and the encryption is a simple application of a password run through a single iteration of a hash function to get the key data, then the encrypted value would actually be the weak point in terms of CPU cost.  In that situation, the answer would be that storing both does not really weaken it, but rather that the encrypted value weakens it.

**Edit** to specifically address the updated question. From a mathematical standpoint, I suspect it would be very difficult to prove that an attacker *cannot* somehow use both pieces of data to reduce the attack time. Some of the attacks that have been devised against hashing and encryption are extremely sophisticated, so it seems in the realm of the possibility that it could be done. And I do know for sure it is possible to reduce the attack time in some situations. A very specific example:

Suppose the attacker can somehow learn the length of the password from the encrypted version. That would vastly decrease the time of brute-forcing the hash version.

Answer (score 2):

In theory it might be "easier" to get the data; in practice, the cost to attack either/both should still be much too great to be feasible. Most encryption algorithms have brute force crack times in the *millions* of years. The same is for good hashing algorithms. In fact you can often think of a hash as an encryption where you throw away the key. So, unless you have billions of different hashes/encrypted values hanging around you can't possible provide enough information to cut the brute force time down enough to matter.

*[update]*

Before anyone else comments on my answer (or votes it down) please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function. A hashed value and a encrypted value have the same relative strength, "strong." So unless you can relate the hash and the encryption algo, the hash doesn't provide any more info about the data then the encrypted version.

Comment: That's not right - hashing "a" gives me a hash that an attacker could easily crack.

Comment: Easily crack a hash! If you can tell me how to do that I'll be very rich.

Comment: -1 "millions of years" is completely depended of the input values. As @thejh pointed out hashing "a" can be quickly found using brute-force.

Comment: HOW!? Give me *1* example! Hashes are cryptographically strong by design! If you could quickly reverse a hash by brute force then the same method could be used on the encryption algo!

Comment: Andrew: You're correct that reversing a hash is RFH (really quite hard).  However, if you've already "forwarded" a bajillion plaintexts into hashes (rainbow table), then you can check for a hash that you've already determined a plaintext for.  This works pretty well for short passwords.

Comment: The meaning of "easy" is relative. But there are hashing algorithms that were already broken like SHA1. See this link: http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html

Comment: Also as hashing algorithms are generally fast to run, passwords encrypted by them are more prone to brute force attacks because you can use pre-built dictionaries easily found on internet. Just run the hashing algorithm to encrypt each word of the dictionary and compare to the encrypted passwords. Weak passwords should be found in short period of time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on several details omitted in the question. Mainly it depends on:

- whether the hash is salted;
- which algorithm and mode of operation is used for encryption;
- other details such as key and IV management.

Consider the scenario in which the hash is not salted and each field is encrypted using AES-CTR mode with the same key and IV.

1. The attacker then chooses a value that is likely to appear in that field.
2. Then he/she hashes it and finds a record in which the hash appears.
3. Then, the attacker looks at the corresponding encryption for which the plaintext is kown.
4. By XORing the ciphertext and the plaintext the attacker recovers the keystream.
5. The attacker can decrypt everything else.

Answer (score 1):

This clearly weakens security. One example:

An attacker that knows nothing about your system might try brute force decryption of the encrypted field. How do they know when they have a successful decryption? (The encrypted field could potentially decrypt to *anything*).

By keeping both hash and encrypted value you have provided a trivial mechanism for an attacker to answer this question (by hashing each attempted decryption).

Comment: This is an interesting answer. Can someone confirm it or discuss it?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it does - there are now two ways to get the data, instead of just one. So long as you can decrypt it in one of the two available ways, you have the data.

Comment: Two seconds faster than me with this.

Comment: I understand your point, its strength is the strength of the weakest one. But they would have to crack it `"independently"`. My question is can the attacker use one to somehow make it easier to crack the other?

Comment: @silow, that would imply some relationship between the hash and the encryption algo; in practice, this almost always not the case.

Comment: With no real details how can anyone know? But it is very unlikely that one of those can be used against the other.

Comment: @GregS I can't think of *any* real relationship between any of the main hash algos and any of the main encryptions algos; That would imply one algo could expose some info about the unprocessed data of the other which seems like something the designers would want to avoid

Comment: @Andrew White: I agree, neither can I.

Answer (score 0):

If I may understand you correctly, you are saying if a hacker gets both the values will he be able to decipher it faster? or like A takes 6 hrs B takes 9 hrs if we combin will he can crack it in 4 hours? right?
Well theoretically I believe he will be able to crack it faster even if it is, in the span of billion years.
The SHA512 is difficult to crack(may be practically impossible as of now) and considering ur encryption is as hard to crack.
Then there will be only one way to go in cracking this, by brute force.
So a simple probability theory applies here, he gets twice as lucky. 
CPU Cycles, time is another side of coin. 
But still we can't say he was a lucky chap and got lucky on his 500th try,if not he may get another chance to get lucky. So theoretically it may be easier and practically as well but then again he should be lucky enough to live that long too.LOL

And if A can be used to crack B? Not really possible as there should be some similarity in hashing and encryption algorithm, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the very fact that the field has 2 variations somehow make it easier for the attacker to use one to make cracking the other easier?

It makes cracking the other variant easier because, once I crack one variant, I'll get more samples of plaintext that corresponds to the encrypted data of the other variant.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, maybe. If the string is very short and somebody cracks it, he has the original value without having to know the key. This especially applies to passwords.

Comment: Even if it isn't a password, the fields are encrypted/hashed for a reason. The information is, in some way, sensitive.

Comment: The downvote was because this answer makes no sense. The question was whether having the hash value makes it easier to crack the encryption. This answer has nothing to do with that. "If somebody cracks it, he has the original value" is true for any encryption, but if you use encryption properly, it is essentially impossible to crack.

Comment: @Graeme Perrow: But if it's just encrypted, it can't be cracked that easy (if it isn't salted with a huge salt).